# paradox in De-Broglie relations!

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

what is wrong with my calculations?!

$E=h\nu$, $p=h/\lambda$. by combining we have $E=pv$ where $v=\lambda\nu$ is velocity of wave and associated particle. but $E=mc^2$ and $p=mv$ and putting this to $E=pv$ says $mc^2=mv^2$ and that is $v=c$ !!

Comment: $E= \frac{1}{2}pv$ refers to the particle velocity, which corresponds to the [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) of the corresponding wave. This is not generally equal to the wave's [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) which is what appears in the equation $v = \lambda \nu$

Comment: $E^2 = m^2c^4 + p^2c^2$

Comment: $E=h\nu$ only for photons which have no mass. $E=pc$ only for photons. There is no paradox.

Answer (score 2):

> what is wrong with my calculations?!

You have to distinguish between group and phase velocity and there are also some factors of $\gamma$ missing.

In terms of angular velocity $\omega = 2\pi\nu$ and wave number $k = \frac{2\pi}\lambda$ the de Broglie relations read
\begin{align}
E &= \hbar \omega \\
p &= \hbar k
\end{align}

It follows
$$
v_\text{phase} = \frac\omega k = \frac Ep
$$

Relativistically, we have $E=\gamma mc^2$ and $p=\gamma m v_\text{particle}$ and thus
$$
v_\text{phase} = \frac{\gamma mc^2}{\gamma m v_\text{particle}} = \frac{c^2}{v_\text{particle}}
$$

In contrast, the group velocity is
$$
v_\text{group} = \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial k} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial p}
$$

From $E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2$ is follows that
$$
2E\frac{\partial E}{\partial p} = 2pc^2 \iff \frac{\partial E}{\partial p} = \frac{pc^2}{E}
$$
and thus
$$
v_\text{group} = \frac{pc^2}{E} = \frac{c^2}{v_\text{phase}} = v_\text{particle}
$$